# Updating value of the document / row in azure cosmosdb in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Evening all,

I am writing small project, and want to add to te website hosted in azure storage (which is static) visit counter.
I want to write short script in python that when called in Azure Functions, it would update a value of the record to be +=1
Way I created a document:

```
## Create a container entry for amount of visits
try:
    item = {
        'id': 'visits',
        'value': 0,
        'description': 'amount of visits'

    }
    container.create_item(body=item)
    print('Successfully added to DB')
except exceptions.CosmosHttpResponseError:
    print('Cant do it')
```

And it looks like that now in the panel:
[Azure CosmosDB Data Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZDn.png)

I want to modify now visits value to be one more each time function will be called.
Trying to sort this out for past two days and I don't get it.
I am absolutely beginner at all of this, never done anything similar in my life, therefore if I could ask for an advice or point me where to look, that would be amazing.

When running:

```
item = container.read_item('visits', partition_key='/value')
item += 1
updated_item = container.upsert_item(item)
```

*I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\DellWS\Desktop\The Cloud Resume Challenge\The-Cloud-Resume-Challenge\function_app.py", line 69, in 
item = container.read_item('visits', partition_key='/value')
.
.
.
azure.cosmos.exceptions.CosmosResourceNotFoundError: (NotFound) Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found,
RequestStartTime: 2024-02-27T19:21:44.4403736Z, RequestEndTime: 2024-02-27T19:21:44.4554468Z,  Number of regions attempted:1 *

Tried it in a different way:

```
## Increment visit value
item_id = 'visits'
item = container.read_item(item=item_id, partition_key='/value')
print(item)

if item:
    ## increment a value by one
    item['value'] += 1
    container.replace_item(item=item, body=item)
    print('Successfully incremented')
else:
    print('Item not found, or couldnt update')
```

and was getting above error code as well.

Comment: you're essentially attempting to change a document's partition key's value, and you can't do that. The partition key value can't change, so this should be something like `/id` or other unchanging property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that you are using /value as partition key, which you also need to look up the item you are trying to work with. I would try the following:

1. Make a new container where your partition key is something like /config_type.
2. Make a new item in that container with whatever ID makes sense for you and the partition key value of /visit_count. This item should also have a property corresponding to the number of visitors.
3. Try that with your code, modifying as needed, and see where you get to.

Don't hesitate to follow up in comments, I have been doing some work in Python using Cosmos DB recently so I don't mind helping to a greater extent if needed.

Comment: "partition key" - not "primary key. But yeah the OP needs to change this.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMakogon, edited accordingly!